# Wordpress not selecting template in child theme subfolder

Tags: wordpress, templates

I have a Wordpress page with the slug `contact` and a custom template file `page-contact.php`

The `page-contact` template file is in a subdirectory of the child theme called `page-templates`, but it won't work unless I move it to the root of the child theme. There are other custom themes in the `page-templates` folder that appear in the Wordpress admin so I'm not sure why this template file won't work there.

Comment: is there an error?sample codes that you have made?

Comment: There is no error, the only difference between my template and the default page is that I have removed the `<?php get_footer(); ?>` line so that I can see that it's working

Comment: have you added comments?on the top of the template you making?what do you mean about won't work?

Comment: No other changes except removing that line.
The contact page uses the template if the template is located in the child theme directory, but if I move it to `child-theme > page-templates` it no longer uses it, it just uses the default page template

Comment: Can you give us at least the file directory of you theme ?

Comment: `website root > wp-content > themes`. Within this I have 2 folders `theme` and `theme-child`

Answer (score 0):

in creating wordpress template based on [wordrpess.org](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/#creating-custom-page-templates-for-global-use) you must have 
an opening PHP comment at the top of the file that states the template’s name.
Example:

```
<?php /* Template Name: Example Template */ ?>
```

Another Sample:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Full Width Page
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Fourteen
 * @since Twenty Fourteen 1.0
 */
```

Comment: If I do this it shows up as an option in the page edit on the Wordpress admin, but it still doesn't use the file, unless I select it

Comment: template page should be selected as the template page.. if your not gonna select the template you have created , how would wordpress use your template?therefore it is necessary that you need to select a template you have created, so that wordpress will know the template it should use.

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/page-templates/
As it says you can call a page template file `page-{slug}.php` and it will use it without being assigned. This works for me when that file is in the root of either the theme or child theme, but not in a sub-folder of these themes, where all the custom page templates are

Comment: have you added one functions.php and style.css with the proper comment at the top of your child themes css?

Comment: Yes I have both those files, I followed the instructions on https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

Comment: @milky_jay did you found a solution for it?

Comment: @Snowball it seems like that you also had the same problem. try checking file permission and the file name. It might help you.

Comment: @Snowball No I just left the template in root of the child-theme